# Cannot resolve symbol 'google'

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio

I recently checked out some code from Git on Android Studio. The project uses Google Maps but when I check my imports such as `import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;` I get an error when I highlight over google saying 'Cannot resolve symbol 'google''. Might anyone know why? Thanks!